# Toggle function requiring 2 clicks

Tags: jquery

I have a series of buttons. Lets call them A, B, C. I attached the toggle method to these buttons. When I click A, a div with some info will be shown. If i click A again, this div will will be removed. When i click B, the div related to A is removed[if still open] and a new div related to B is shown. It's just a basic toggle we see in many websites.

However, when i click A, then B and then A again, the A will take 2 clicks to show its div. Thats because the second function in the toggle is triggered as it is still in queue.

Look at this code. I am just changing text of the button here for demo.

http://jsfiddle.net/BxFqf/

How to prevent it from taking 2 clicks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bind a click event to the buttons and change the tet accordingly instead of using toggle. I would use .each()

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. .each() combined with classes did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

That's because `.toggle` keeps the state of the item you're toggling and states of different buttons are not related

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to achieve the desired behavior with a "naive" use of `toggle` like that. What you need to do is "remember" the state of each button, so you can react accordingly when it's clicked. Since reacting almost always involves applying styles, using an HTML class is a good option for remembering state as well (you can reuse the class for styling).

See an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sNY2b/).

Comment: Thanks but i can't achieve what i need with simple change of class as it involves adding some HTML. Using the same example you gave, can you edit it so that the text of the buttons change or something other than just CSS styles?

Comment: @Sparda: Simply use `hasClass` to read the state of the clicked button, and do whatever you want based on that. For example, http://jsfiddle.net/eNn6Q/.

Comment: Thanks Jon. Did exactly that.