# jquery toggle needs 2 clicks

Tags: jquery, jquery-click-event

Here's a jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/FVuvC/

In the jquery, it makes the green triangle pull out the container then the red triangle push it back in, but it requires 2 clicks in order for that to happen. How do I go about making it so that it only needs 1 click on both triangles?

```
$(function () {
    $("#clickmeright, #clickmeleft").toggle(function () {
        $(this).parent().animate({
            right: '0px'
        }, {
            queue: false,
            duration: 500
        });
    }, function () {
        $(this).parent().animate({
            right: '-170px'
        }, {
            queue: false,
            duration: 500
        });
    });
});
```

I've looked up other questions on the site but I still don't get it. Such as:

[JQuery Toggle Issue, Requires Two Clicks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9445502/jquery-toggle-issue-requires-two-clicks)

[Toggle function requiring 2 clicks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8783317/toggle-function-requiring-2-clicks)

The most I've gotten from them is that I have to change the toggle to a click function instead. So that should show you where I'm at with understanding this stuff. Also, could someone recommend some good sources for learning this?

Comment: As you mention, use `.click()` and inside it, use `.toggle()` because you also need animation.

Comment: wrap the 2 arrows in another element and use that single element to click on. At first I didn't understand issue because I missed red trangle with my mouse and clciked green to close and it worked... would be same if trangles shared a parent and user has bigger click area

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happen because event handler toggles function not on both element, but on each of them separately (you would not wonder if `$('#e1,#e2').click(function)` will not fire event on both elements if you click on e1 ), to workaround I would to make something like:

```
$(function () {
    var $clickmeright=$("#clickmeright");
    $("#clickmeleft").click(function() {
        $clickmeright.click();
    })
    $clickmeright.toggle(function () {
        $(this).parent().animate({
            right: '0px'
        }, {
            queue: false,
            duration: 500
        });
    }, function () {
        $(this).parent().animate({
            right: '-170px'
        }, {
            queue: false,
            duration: 500
        });
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/FVuvC/1/

Comment: toggle(); first hides a div and then shows it. So if the div is already hidden then on the first click toggle seems to do nothing. From second click it starts working properly. Actually it always works properly. I am not able to figure out what to do so that toggle shows the div first. If anyone can answer this hats off to him!!