# Toggling Multiple Menus Requires 2 Clicks

Tags: jquery, menu, toggle, dropdown

I am setting up a form where I have multiple dropdowns each individually enabled by a button. There are 7 of these. I need a user to be able to run down the list of buttons and turn however many they want on and off.

As you can see by the JSFiddle below, if you try and click on "Toggle Disabled" and then on "Toggle Disabled 2," and so on, it won't register that second click.

http://jsfiddle.net/x9k72tr2/

I've tried using:

```
$("#toggle-disabled2").click(function(){
  state = !state;
  $widget2.multiselect(state ? 'disable' : 'enable');
});
```

Then I realized that didn't make any sense.

I was then wondering if you could do this with perhaps .hasClass, but I don't know how I'd implement it in this setting.

EDIT:
I found there's quite a few 2 click questions asked, such as this one:
[Toggle function requiring 2 clicks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8783317/toggle-function-requiring-2-clicks)

http://jsfiddle.net/sNY2b/

Still, I am having a hard time on how to do this with my widget. Also noticed that there is multiple variables, and that even if one var is broken, it will mess with all multiselects. So I tried changing it, hoping it would solve to problem, too:

```
var $widget1 = $("select" + id).multiselect(), state = true;

$("#toggle-disabled1").click(function(){
  state = !state;
  $widget1.multiselect(state ? 'disable' : 'enable');
});
$("#toggle-disabled2").click(function(){
  state = !state;
  $widget2.multiselect(state ? 'disable' : 'enable');
});
$("#toggle-disabled3").click(function(){
  state = !state;
  $widget3.multiselect(state ? 'disable' : 'enable');
});
```

No cigar, I'm down a rabbit hole.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out with the help of a programmer better than I. :)

The states needs to be also separated into unique IDs. The two clicks occur because as follows:

1. Toggle first div, state goes to enabled
2. Toggle second div, state assumed to be enabled, and executes to toggle to disabled (which it already is)
3. And so on.

The working JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/x9k72tr2/1/

The working code:

```
var $widget1 = $("#select1").multiselect(); state1 = true;
var $widget2 = $("#select2").multiselect(); state2 = true;
var $widget3 = $("#select3").multiselect(); state3 = true;

$("#toggle-disabled1").click(function(){
  state1 = !state1;
  $widget1.multiselect(state1 ? 'disable' : 'enable');
});
$("#toggle-disabled2").click(function(){
  state2 = !state2;
  $widget2.multiselect(state2 ? 'disable' : 'enable');
});
$("#toggle-disabled3").click(function(){
  state3 = !state3;
  $widget3.multiselect(state3 ? 'disable' : 'enable');
});
```